# CSS Radial Gradient?

Tags: css, gradient, radial-gradients

So I made something simple like this in photoshop for my header: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6zKR.png

and I've been doing research on radial gradients in CSS and I found how to get to this point, but I don't know how to adjust it to get it to look more like the photoshop one.

Any help would be appreciated!

```css
#header {
 height: 220px;
 width: 100%;
 background-image:
 radial-gradient(
   circle closest-side,
   #6fa5d9,
   #51789d
 );
}
```

```html
<header id="header"></header>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would want something like this:

```
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #50779d 0%,#50779d 37%,#557fa6 47%,#557ea5 51%,#50779d 59%,#50789d 100%);
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/bemumitate/1/edit)

[Further Reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient)

Comment: thank you that did it!  Except "circle" instead of "elipse" at center